# change direction of HorizontalScrollView - android

Tags: android, scroll

I use this code in my xml :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/hsvv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:measureAllChildren="false"
android:scrollbars="none" >
```

now it scroll from left to right - how can i change the direction?
- - - - - - - --->

EDIT:
I will exaplain my self better :I now use horizontal linear layout and indise 10 textView.  My app languge is RTL - > so I want the item will start from right and enable the user to scroll left inorder to see the other items (which have no place in the screen)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? how are you going to populate subviews to your view?

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll it programmatically to the end.

Also if your populating suff dynamically. You can use horizontal linear layout. When Adding new items(addChild(child, 0)) scroll the view by new item width.

Depending of your expectation.

Comment: I will exaplain my self better :I now use horizontal linear layout and indise 10 textView.  My app languge is RTL - > so I want the item will start from right and enable the user to scroll left inorder to see the other items (which have no place in the screen)

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the HorizontalScrollView:

```
android:scrollX="100000dp"
```

Comment: what does it mean? I get error: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'scrollX' with value '100000').

Comment: I've edited the answer to use DPs instead of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```